# Make ASP.NET web-application auto recompile in iis

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can i change class property in asp.net web application and upload the new class without compiling it to iis and see the new value display on the page .

Comment: classes are never uploaded to IIS. Binaries are uploaded... so no, you can not upload the class to IIS with or without compiling. When you compile the code and create binary and upload it to IIS, the APPPool is bound to recycle. Can you explain the use case you are trying to solve?

Comment: As Chetan says you cannot make changes to classes. However you can make changes to static files including cshtml and upload them to your webserver without recompiling.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: this is not true. Classes can be uploaded to the `App_Code` folder and the source code is recompiled upon the very first requests to your site.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i need to have some sort of not upload the dll file to the server

Comment: @WiktorZychla yes this is true for website version of the asp.net webforms , not the web application .

Comment: @MohammedAkram: [should work for web apps too](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html).